# Two dimensional Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation, stieltjes-integral

**In an old text I am reading I have encountered something that looks like a two-dimensional Riemann-Stieltjes integral. I am wondering if there are any good books or texts on this subject?**

**Update:**
It is requested that I write the integral. There are a lot of details here, I don't need help with the details I only need help with the request of sources.

The Riemann sum is:

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^n\sum\limits_{m=1}^{n'}v^{s_r+s_m'-2s}\Gamma_{\nu jk}(s,s_r,s_m')E_{\nu s}\{[Y(s,t_r)-Y(s,t_{r-1})][Y(s,t_{m'})-Y(s,t_{m-1}')]\}$.

It is said that this converges to:
$\int_{\Omega}v^{t+\tau-2s}\Gamma_{\nu j k}(s,t,\tau)d_{(t,\tau)}r_{vs}(t,\tau)$. Where
$\Omega$ is a certain subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is also said that

$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial t \partial \tau}r_{\nu s}(t,\tau)=P_{\nu j}(s,t)\mu_{jk}(t)P_{kj}(t,\tau)\mu_{jk}(\tau)$.

Then it said that the integral above equals:
$\int_\Omega v^{t+\tau-2s}\Gamma_{vjk}(s,t,\tau)P_{\nu j}(s,t_1(t,\tau))\mu_{jk}(t_1(t,\tau))P_{kj}(t_1(t,\tau),t_2(t,\tau))\mu_{jk}(t_2(t,\tau))d(\tau,t)$.

Where $t_1,t_2$ are min and max functions, $\Gamma$ is a given function.

Comment: Can you write out what your example looks like explicitly?  Then we'll know for sure what kind of integral this is for sure.

Comment: @TobyBartels I added the Riemann-sum and integral. I actually didn't want to do this because it is a lot of details there.

Comment: See Alomari's thesis [Numerous approximations of Riemann-Stieltjes double integrals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.05038v1).

Comment: Thanks.  Now after putting you through that work, I'm sorry that I don't have an answer.  But I do understand the question better!

Comment: @TobyBartels Hmm. Are you really sure? :)